# PDB symbols could not be loaded (igvk32.pdb not loaded)

Tags: c++, 3d, direct3d, vulkan

While compiling my Vulkan program I was getting this error
[image: ref1]

[image: ref2]

I have tried the Microsoft symbol services but it didn't work.

Comment: `igvk32.pdb` is the PDB which matches the igvk32.dll binary which is an Intel dll [presumaby it stands for intel graphics vulcan 32 bit]. No idea on how you'd get the PDB for it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When debugging your own code you do not need none of those, because you already have the correct driver binary on your PC. You will not be getting any additional info (symbols such as function names in the driver), since the drivers are not open-source.

I think in default VS settings it should land you on the last known position before the code crashed. Otherwisely inspect your Threads window, and Call Stack window to identify at which point of execution of your code you are.

---

In some cases you do need the correct driver binary to make sense of the call stack. I.e. when you debug from memory dump that was made on a different PC than the one you are debugging on (which I think is not your case).

Intel symbol server is not publicly available. But best to ask them directly rather than ask 3rd party strangers.

- AMD binaries: https://gpuopen.com/learn/amd-driver-symbol-server/
- NV binaries: https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-driver-symbol-server

Comment: It seems that it is not necessary as you say . btw i have tried this link but it didn't help https://software.intel.com/sites/downloads/symbols/

Comment: @RITIKGUPTA Right, AIS these do not include the "actual" symbols, as the drivers are not open-source. If your code stops inside the driver, you still get "No symbols". On crash though VS typically shows the last known named function. Either you have some odd config on, or maybe it is something executed on a separate thread and no known funcion actually is in its call stack.

Comment: The Intel "symbol" server only provides the binaries, not the pdbs. Are your function names really that secret, Intel? Nobody expects private symbols... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/pdbstripped-strip-private-symbols